# Kibana maps - filter geo_points in one index using geofences (geo_shapes) from another index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index which has a geo_point field, and I have another index that has a geo_shape field.  I want to show only geo_points in some specific geo_shape on Kibana maps, so what I want to do is to filter the geo_points by selecting one geo_shape. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed answer can be found in [Allow to upload custom Geoshape to filter data](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/53695), here are the steps:

1. upload the shape in geojson format using the GeoJson-upload feature (Add Source > add Geojson). -> the shape or shapes are added to the Map as a layer
2. Configure a tooltip for this shape Layer settings > tooltips > add tooltip field
3. Click on the shape on the map and select the "filter by geometry" action from the tooltip -> this will filter other geometries based on that shape.